# Where to ask general life questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I fear this may be your typical "Yahoo Answers" type of question, and thus may not belong on *any* stack exchange site. I am prepared to accept that as the ultimate answer.

I have a question regarding the "Where did you grow up?" type of questions on surveys and the like, mainly within the context of my own personal childhood that makes the question less intuitive.

Where (if any) is the best stack exchange site for such a question?

Comment: Are you asking why the question "Where did you grow up?" would be on a survey?

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear. I'm asking how I would answer such a question. For example, for someone who lived in the same place from age 1 to 18 the answer is clear. But what if until I was 18 I never lived in one place for more than 4 years? I know I'm probably overthinking this but the question expects a single answer.

Comment: Usually those questions are for gathering statistics about where the people answering the more central/important questions are from... It allows them to make statements like "25% of Americans think X..." While "30% of Canadians think Y..."

Comment: That may be true; however my question is more about how to answer the question and less about why it exists. Also the question requires a more granular answer. If it were strictly what country that would be easy. It's looking for City / State in the US.

Comment: My point was that your answer to the peripheral question isn't really important. Tell them what ever you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, unfortunately, it doesn't sound like that would be a fantastic fit for any (current) Stack Exchange site.

There are a couple sites in the SE network related data collection, like [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com), but the focus there is more on the actual process of collecting data, rather than your question about how to answer someone who is collecting said data.

In this particular case, it sounds like the best place to ask would be the survey-givers themselves. That question could definitely be left up to interpretation, as you've certainly discovered, so it would be hard for anyone on one of these relatively generalized Stack Exchange sites to give you a definitive answer on what the designers were looking for when they asked that question.

This question is somewhat related to the classic "where can I ask interview questions" (it's asked from time to time on here and Meta Stack Overflow), to which the answer is generally something along the lines of "it depends on the question." What I've said above is related specifically to your given example, but it's quite possible that other examples under your "general life questions" umbrella would be more appropriate. You'd just have to evaluate on a case-by-case basis, I'd say. You can always check out https://stackexchange.com/sites, which has a list of all the sites in the network. Sometimes, even as a marginally experienced member of a number of communities, I like to go there and refresh my memory on what sites are active.